# He stayed a week vs he stayed for a week

Tags: expressions, expression-choice, variants

> - He stayed a week vs He stayed *for* a week
> - I consider her my friend vs I consider her *as* my friend.
> - I don't know whether he can be there vs I don't know *if* he can be there

I often hear the above sentences and their variants.

What is the basis for choice...
Which would not sound odd ?

Comment: > We can say (or write) one or other of each of these pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> He stayed a week
>   vs
>   He stayed for a week

I would say that just '*a week*' would be more casual, and something you would speak, whereas '*for a week*' is more formal (and gramatically correct) and would prbably be written.
However here I would say that the diference is more or less negligible.

> I consider her my friend
>   vs
>   I consider her as my friend.

I would use '*I consider her my friend*'.

'*I consider her **as** my friend*' sounds a little odd to me (albeit perhaps gramatically correct) and I wouldn't use that.
The one instance I might use the latter could be for emphasis, or speaking the sentense slowly or angrily.

> I don't know whether he can be there
>   vs
>   I don't know if he can be there

I would say that to me they are identical (in terms of *interchangeability* and *naturalness*.)

Answer (score 1):

In the first two sets, both options are completely acceptable.

In the third set, both options could easily be interchangeable but there is a general rule that seems wise to consider:

***[Condition vs Alternative](http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/if-whether.html)***:

> **Condition**
>
> In many cases, *if* and *whether* can be used interchangeably without affecting the meaning.  Below are some subtle differences in formal
>   use. Use *if* to indicate ***one condition that requires an action***. If X is
>   true, then do Y.
>
> *I don't know **if** he can be there*.
>
> **Alternative**:
>
> Use *whether* to indicate ***two conditions, alternates, that require an
>   action***: yes or no,  X or Y.  If X or Y is true, then do Z.
>
> *I don't know **whether** he can be there (or not).*